# Showing one time the duplicated ID in Map Operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetched a json data like this to show matches of different league:

```
    "league": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Africa Cup of Nations",
    "country": "World",
    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/6.png",
    "flag": null,
    "season": 2023,
    "round": "Group Stage - 2"
},
"teams": {
    "home": {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Morocco",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/31.png",
        "winner": null
    },
    "away": {
        "id": 1508,
        "name": "Congo DR",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1508.png",
        "winner": null
.......

        "league": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Africa Cup of Nations",
    "country": "World",
    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/6.png",
    "flag": null,
    "season": 2023,
    "round": "Group Stage - 2"
},
"teams": {
    "home": {
        "id": 1507,
        "name": "Zambia",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1507.png",
        "winner": null
    },
    "away": {
        "id": 1489,
        "name": "Tanzania",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1489.png",
        "winner": null
    }
......

     "league": {
    "id": 844,
    "name": "Ligue 1",
    "country": "Congo",
    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/844.png",
    "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cd.svg",
    "season": 2023,
    "round": "Regular Season - 11"
},
"teams": {
    "home": {
        "id": 3170,
        "name": "Diables Noirs",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3170.png",
        "winner": null
    },
    "away": {
        "id": 16798,
        "name": "V.Club Mokanda",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/16798.png",
        "winner": null
    }
},
"goals": {
    "home": null,
    "away": null
},

......
```

I show content of matches of a league like that :

```
 Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).map(([key, value]) => value.map((match, index) => 
     <div className="card_header d-flex flex-column g-10">
     // if() ==> make condition here to show the header one time for every league even I have multiple matches...
    <LeagueHeader img={match?.league?.logo} title={match?.league?.name} subtitle={match?.league?.country} />
    </div>
  //}
  ....
 <MatchMonthCard match={match} index={index} key={key + '_' + index}/> 
 ))
```

I can't move the header outside of MAP operation then the issue is for example for `Africa Cup of Nations` is duplicated twice so I will have a duplicated header in `<LeagueHeader>`?

I tried a lot of solutions, for example using `Set constructor` but that not help me to show one league header for every competitions, any Idea?